# Is serializer field level validation called if initial_data does not have a key for that field name?

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

```
data = {...}

MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  ...
  def validate_[my_field_name]()
     ...
```

The data dictionary does not contain the key `my_field_name`

Then will the `validate_[my_field_name]()` method be called when I call

```
serializer = MySerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, No.

This is something that causes me pain, fairly often too.  There are a few things you can do:

- Set `required=True` when you declare your field
- Supply a `default=`, if that is sufficient

The `validate` method of the serializer is always called, and you can add something in there if you want to

```
class A(Serializer):
   
    must_send = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    
 
    def validate(self, attrs):
        if 'key' not in attrs:
            attrs.setdefault('key', some_calculation())

        # important!
        return attrs
```